# Assert element exists after all XHR requests finished

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I'm visiting a page which is fetching data Asynchronously (multiple XHR requests), and then asserting if a certain DOM element is visible/exists in the page.

So far I was only able to get the page and the data fetched with using [cy.wait()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Aliases) either with an arbitrary time, or by aliasing the actual request, and using the promise-like syntax to make sure my `cy.get()` is done after the XHR response has completed. [image]

Here is what doesn't work:

```
 before(() => {
    cy.login();
    cy.server();
    cy.route('/v0/real-properties/*').as('getRealPropertyDetails');
    cy.visit('/real-properties/1/real-property-units-table');
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('platform_session');
  });

  after(() => {
    cy.clearCookies();
  });

  context('when viewport is below 1367', () => {
    it('should be closed by default', () => {
      cy.wait('@getRealPropertyDetails'); // the documentation says this is the way to go
      sSizes.forEach((size) => {
        cy.viewport(size[0], size[1]);
        cy.get('.v-navigation-drawer--open.real-property-details-sidebar').should('not.exist');
      });
    });
```

Adding `cy.wait(1000);` in the `before()` or `beforeEach()` hooks also works, but this is not really an acceptable solution.

What works, but not sure if this is the way to do this (I would have to add this for every page, would be quite annoying) :

```
    it('should be closed by default', () => {
  cy.wait('@getRealPropertyDetails').then(() => {
    sSizes.forEach((size) => {
      cy.viewport(size[0], size[1]);
      cy.get('.real-property-details-sidebar').should('not.be.visible');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have browser reloads there (beforeEach), which could potentially wipe out the route spy, but not sure why `cy.wait().then` would work. I would try switching from `before` to `beforeEach` though, creating things once is always trickier than letting them be created before each test

Comment: the real question is why do I need to use .wait at all - I thought cypress would wait automatically before evaluating the assertion/get in such a scenario

Comment: well, it is YOUR application making a request, so how does the test know that you want to wait for this XHR at a particular moment? You have to tell the test "wait for XHR before running next step of the test"